# use of if and only if

Tags: real-analysis, logic

My instructor gave me the following question:

> Prove that $\lim_{x \to x_0}f(x) = L$ if and only if $\lim_{h \to 0}f(x_0 + h) = L$ if and only if $\lim_{h \to 0}(f(x_0 + h) - L) = 0$.

Can we use if and only if two times in one sentence? The statement looks correct but the expression makes me very uncomfortable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$p \iff q \iff r$ is just another way of saying $p \iff q$ and $ q \iff r$